# Facebook-Login not possible anymore in my Ionic 5 mobile app using firebase/auth

Tags: firebase, facebook, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic5

I am developing a hybrid mobile app using Ionic 5/Angular and Firebase. The login with facebook does not work anymore. It seems that facebook changed some policies and since then it is not possible anymore to get it running.

I get a screen like this always:

[image: Facebook-Error-Screen]

You can reproduce this when checking out for example https://github.com/ionicthemes/ionic5-firebase-authentication
That is not my project, but I have a similar problem. All other auth methods work.
The only thing I found is that the v8.0 oauth dialog from facebook is being called including a query parameter "context_uri: http://localhost". That's the only thing I found that could trigger this maybe. I don't know how to change/fix that though.

Comment: From the example under https://ionic5-firebase-authentication.web.app/sign-in, I can trigger the Facebook login dialog just fine. The web login flow requires using HTTPS, that is not a recent change, has been like that for quite a while now. Is the problem that you can not really use HTTPS in your hybrid app context somehow, or what exactly?

Comment: This error comes up only on the mobile device while being not in development mode. To see this you must do a "ionic cap run android". Everything has been set up with https. This used to work...

Answer (score 0):

The web login flow requires using HTTPS.
If you use cordova, you will need to use a webview (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview) to embed an https page that contain your facebook connexion

Comment: Sure, everything has been set up with https. The problem is coming when starting the app on the mobile in production mode. I believe the problem is that ionic starts the app locally on the mobile using http://localhost which can not be changed so easily as far as I know.